# Ionic 2 Debounce on Gesture Event

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs

How to bind Rx/Js denounce to ionic 2 gesture event ?

```
        this.pressGesture = new Gesture(this.content._elementRef.nativeElement);
        this.pressGesture.listen();
        this.pressGesture.on('pinch', e => { 
            console.log('testing');
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
const pinch = Observable.fromEvent(this.pressGesture, 'pinch')
  .debounceTime(500);
```

The [`fromEvent`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromEvent) method accepts types that conform to standard `EventEmitter` like interfaces and as such is able to automatically bind the event using the `on` method. This lifts the `Gesture` object into a stream and allows you to use the standard RxJS operators on it.

Comment: superb! you rocks!